# When sending html code through PHP/AJAX it escapes the double quotes

Tags: html, php, javascript, ajax

On click I'm creating a new .html webpage. My HTML code is stored in a variable called content. But finally when the webpage is the made, the code automatically has \" (it escapes the double quotes). Is there a way for me to do it so that the webpage doesn't have escaped double quotes?

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="makePage()">Generate Link</button>
<script src="makePage.js">
</script>
<script>
var img = document.getElementById("img").value;
var content = document.getElementById("content").value;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function makePage(){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
     }
     var content = '<html><head><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes"><meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir"><meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral"><meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here."><meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg"></head><body></body></html>';
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://ahansabharwal.com/makePage.php?content=" + content, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$content = $_GET["content"];
$file = "" . uniqid() . ".html";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
echo $file;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is enabled in PHP (this is deprecated in later versions of PHP). In which case you'll need to call [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the `$_GET` value before processing it.

Something like:

```
<?php
$content = $_GET['content'];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
     $content = stripslashes($content);
}
```

You should also be URL encoding the `content` before sending it in the GET request (the `encodeURIComponent()` method in JavaScript). However, this is a lot to send via GET, consider using a POST request instead.

Comment: Alright, so this should be my code?:                                                     $content = stripslashes("content");
$content = $_GET["content"];

Comment: Well, something like that, I've added a code example. You need to check that `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled first. On later versions of PHP this is not set. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: In older versions of PHP, `magic_quotes_gpc` is on by default. Yes, you can disable this setting on your server. However, in order to write portable code (if you change servers or use the same code elsewhere) then you need to at least check for this and process it accordingly. It is an unfortunate legacy of PHP, however, it has been completely removed as of PHP 5.4.